# Need help in applying css to alternate rows in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am forming rows in the HTML table using JavaScript by using a for loop.

Here is my for loop for creating rows in HTML table:

```
for(var j=0;j<5;j++) {

     var row =  createNewRow(obj);
     jQuery("#test").append(row);

}

function createNewRow (obj)
{
    // html for creating five rows per page

    var str="";
    str+=<tr>;
    str +=<td>;
    str +=<td>;

    ......

    str +=<tr>;

    return str;
}
```

Here I have created five rows per page. I need help to apply CSS to alternate rows in table.

Comment: That can be done with CSS

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #CCC;
}
```

Or

```
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: #f00
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me how to apply css instead of using nth child

Comment: @user13763 this is CSS.

Comment: i have five rows per page means 1st row should be in red and 2nd in green and so on. Now in second page that is 6th row it should be in red and not in green

Comment: Give the two tables different classes or id's. @user13763

Comment: its not two tables a single table which displays records that is 5 records per page

Comment: So on two separate `.html` documents?

Comment: not 2 separate documents i have a single table which displays 5 records then when i click on 2nd page it displays next 5 records and so on

Comment: Use different classes/ID's for the tables @user13763

Answer (score 2):

Try with CSS:

```css
table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    //styles odd rows
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td {
    //styles even rows
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#000000");
  $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#000000");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

**CSS**

```css
table tr:nth-child(odd){
    //styles odd rows
}
table tr:nth-child(even){
    //styles even rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var j=0;j<5;j++) {

     var row =  createNewRow(obj,j);
     jQuery("#test").append(row);

}

function createNewRow (obj,j)
{
    // html for creating five rows per page

    var str="";
    str+=<tr; 
    if(j%2==0){ str += class='even'>;}
    if(j%2==1){ str +=  class='odd'>;}
    str +=<td>;
    str +=<td>;

    ......

    str +=<tr>;

    return str;
}
```

Then apply css for the class odd and even

Comment: this is my for loop  where from and to index depends on the page

Comment: fromIndex= // anything depends on the page 
toIndex= // depends on the page 

   for(var j=fromIndex;toIndex>j;j++) {
   var row =  createRow(obj);
   jQuery("#test").append(row);
     
  }

Comment: say for example i am on third page then from index = 10 and toindex is 14 since array starts from 0

Comment: Not a problem...the above program ll work...u r gng to find that no is odd or even..if its odd u r gng to give one class name

Comment: see 10/2 - need background as red same 14/2 will get background red now in next page that is 15th index also should get red since it is next page . so it wont work